# How to filter Delimited Variable using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

My Input Dataframe is

```
list_of_dicts1 = {"Filter":["c",'a|b']}
test1 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts1)
list_of_dicts2 = {"C":["d",'a', 'b']}
test2 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts2)
```

Output Desired is

```
list_of_dicts3 = {"C":['a', 'b']}
test3 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts3)
```

How can I filter data frame test2 based on Filter column (which is pipe delimited) of test1 data frame using pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with split and explode values splitted by `|` by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
df = test2[test2['C'].isin(test1['Filter'].str.split('|').explode())]
print (df)
   C
1  a
2  b
```

For oldier pandas versions:

```
df = test2[test2['C'].isin(test1['Filter'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack())]
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have the variables 'a' and 'b' separated, then:

```
test3=test1[test1['Filter'].isin(test2['C'])]
```